# testing confusion

Tags: solidity, dapps, testing, unittesting, test

I have `addOwner()` like this:

```
function addOwner(address _owner) public onlyOwner {
        require(!owners[_owner]);
        owners[_owner] = true;
    }
```

I was testing for **function can not be called by others except owner**.
Test script:

```
it("function can not be called by others except owner", async function(){
            const {multisig, acc5 } = await loadFixture(
                deployMultisigFixture
            )
        const owner = acc5.address
        const _owner = await ethers.getSigner(owner)
        assert.isNotOk(multisig.connect(_owner).addOwner(), "error")
        })
```

where acc5 was not set as owner at the time of deployment.
here i am getting this error:

```
AssertionError: error: expected Promise{…} to be falsy
```

*multisig.connect(_owner).addOwner()* is falsy, because _owner is not really the owner, so it should pass, is not it??

Comment: Shouldn't you add "await" to the assert.isNotOk? Something like assert.isNotOk(await multisig.connect(_owner).addOwner(), "error").

Answer (score 0):

In Ownable pattern, the owner address is set up at contract deploying, setting the TX sender's address, as owner address.

Are you testing with Truffle, or Hardhat? You can develop your testing scripts in order to execute the logic, following the sequence you need.

Check out this link for Hardhat: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts

Check out this link for Truffle: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/debug-test/write-tests-in-javascript/